# Validating the Date in a range of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DataFormat()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("QC").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Value = "MM/01/YYYY" Then
Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    Else
      Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End If
      Next i
End Sub
```

I am just validating the values in cells K. It has date as 11/1/2017 and cells is formatted to Nov-17. By the above code i am validating if it contains first day of the month and this code is not working.

Comment: Its not updating still. The code is running well and daydate is being assigned a value. But still the color is white for the one which have day values as 2. Please help.

Comment: Right, that s the issue with 2 IF in each other. Now it is corrected check again ;)

Comment: So when i try to debug the code the code is running well till "If Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" And Day(daydate) = 1 Then" and after that its going to end if and again end if. That means its not taking colorindex part into consideration.

Comment: What is your error code? and did it stop at first row?

Comment: Its not taking second IF into consideration. Like it is running fine till second if and then its going to else, the condition and then endif. This means where color index =2 is written its not working for that.

Comment: daydate should have a date format, if not the first if will never work. If all of your cells have dates inside, you can also delete the first if. 
For this it is a bit hard to help without seeing your data

Comment: So if u look at the cell it is being reflected as Nov-2017 however if u double-click on that cell it will appear as 11/1/2017. Does this help you??

Comment: Ok then you were not using the right numberformat either, I have deleted it, see the update on the code

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!!! :). So it means due to different format of the cell it was unable to consider it as mm/dd/yyyy format??

Comment: exactly. Right now your format is smth like MMM.YY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue was mostly coming from

```
Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").value
```

which is not checking the right date. To check the date format you need to add the `.NumberFormat`

Also the numberformat you are using `mm/dd/yyyy` is different from what you have on your excel in the form Nov-17, so you can delete it.

Now in order to check the day of the month you can simply use the function `Day()` which only works with a string inside.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DataFormat()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim daydate As String
LastRow = Worksheets("QC").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 3 To LastRow
      daydate = Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Value
         If IsDate(daydate) Then

             If Day(daydate) = 1 Then
                 Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
             Else
                 Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
             End If

         Else
             Worksheets("QC").Cells(i, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
         End If
   Next i
End Sub
```